# 3rd party software restriction

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install 3rd party software on Ubuntu 16.04 but is not working. It does open up the .deb's on the Ubuntu Software app and shows the install option, you can press the 'Install' button and installation seems to start but it'll get stuck immediately and won't go any further ever.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a bug. You can install deb packages using `dpkg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `gdebi` the 16.04 Software Center is actually bugged (but already pacthed upstream), so till that update hits live use `gdebi`.
To install gdebi do in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

After that start it with:

```
gksudo gdebi-gtk
```

This will after prpomting you for your password open the Gdebi-GUI version.

Now just open your .deb file by

```
File --> open
```

Then hit install package. This way you mostly wont run into dependency problems.

---

Another solution is doing it via terminal with `dpkg`(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename>.deb
```

If you run into messages saying something about unmet dependencies do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this will aswell do it, but the `gdebi`solutioin is more hassle free.

Comment: When will the bug fix be sent to us?

Comment: The new Ubuntu Softwares also lacks lots of softwares.

Comment: @JulianLai dont know just heard this yesterday in [AU-Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) but my guess is, it wont be long.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the help... but it didn't work. I tried with gdebi, it does open the .deb, it does install it (apparently), but then the app executable icon is nowhere to be found. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Not all 3rd party software has icons, youre sure there should be one ?

Comment: I guess. I'm trying to install the Mega sync client. I use to have it installed on Ubuntu 14.10, and it did have an icon.